# 2D-Array manipulation through pointer parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm creating a set of functions that takes a pointer to a 2D-Array
and fills the array with some data

This is how I got it right now:

```
17 void m4identity(float *m[4][4]) {
18    *m = (float[4][4]) { { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
19                         { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
20                         { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
21                         { 0, 0, 0, 1 } };
22 }
```

But unfortunately I get a compiler error:

```
linalg.c:18:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float *[4]’ from type ‘float (*)[4]’
```

Questions:

1. What is the difference between `(*)[4]` and `*[4]`?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

   I initially tried to return a pointer to the array created inside the function
   but this threw another compiler error because it would be out of scope.
   I also want to avoid allocating space for the array from within the function as
   that would be hard to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between `(*)[4]` and `*[4]`?

The `[]` declaration specifier has higher precedence, so `float *arr[4]` declares an array of 4 pointers-to-`float`, while `float (*arr)[4]` declares a pointer-to-array-of-4-`float`.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Just let the array decay into a pointer and use assignments:

```
void m4identity(float m[4][4])
{
    memset(m, 0, 4 * sizeof(m[0]));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        m[i][i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: note that this is exactly the same as declaring `void m4identity(float (*m)[4])`